# How to have watch in an Express/Angular project in VS Code?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a Node Express project created via `express-generator` in VS Code. I then added Angular through @angular/cli via `ng new`.

The project works fine. I run it in debug by launching the main Node project. However, I have to run `ng build` and restart the Code debugging session each time I made changes to the Angular project. How do I set up the watch mode for the Javascript to be rebuilt when changes are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `ng serve` command.

From Angular quick start guide https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#serve

> The ng serve command launches the server, watches your files, and rebuilds the app as you make changes to those files.

Comment: Where are the output files, ie the index.html and the .js files, generated by `ng serve` located?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng build` you can use `ng serve`.It will watch automatically for changes.

Comment: Isn't `ng serve` running its own web server? Will it clash with the main Node web server for the project?

Comment: No it won't conflict as it will update the angular code only what you manually do by `ng build`